# Getting NullPointerException when calling ArrayList.get() in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, nullpointerexception

So I have a chatroom, and it used to work but I changed the code slightly to try some things out and they didn't work, so I tried to revert back to my original code but I'm not sure what I did wrong because now it is throwing a NullPointerException. My code has an ArrayList of PrintWriters and a method showAll() which does as it says; send a message to all people in the chatroom. So basically what I'm wondering is how come I am getting the exception?

```
    //This is the main code, used to add printwriters to the arraylist and to connect to clients
    //The Communicate thread is used to get input from users and use the showAll() method with that input
    public void listen() {
        listWriters = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            portnum = getPortNumber(scanner);
            System.out.println("Listening on " + portnum);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portnum);
            while(true) {
                clientcommunicate = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection accepted: " + clientcommunicate.toString());

                PrintWriter client = new PrintWriter(clientcommunicate.getOutputStream(), true);
                listWriters.add(client);
                Thread t = new Thread(new Communicate(clientcommunicate));
                t.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe);
            System.err.println("Error.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    //This uses a printwriter obtained in the Communicate thread; the thread initializes a socket in it with the socket obtained in the constructor
    public void showAll(String msg, PrintWriter printwriter) {
        for(int i = 0; i < listWriters.size(); i++) { //this is where the exception is thrown
            if(!listWriters.get(i).equals(printwriter)) { //if I change the paramater listWriters.size() to a regular integer like 3, and only create 2 clients or even less, the exception is thrown here instead
                listWriters.get(i).println(msg);
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Ok so I'm not getting the error anymore but now I can't seem to send messages. If I send the message from my client side, there are no errors but the message doesn't show up on either client.

Answer (score 6):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` thrown because you are trying to dereference (i.e. call methods on, or read fields from), a variable which is `null`.

In this case, it's clear that `listWriters` is null (because it is the only variable which is dereferenced on the line where the exception occurs - look for `.` characters).  Since this gets assigned in your `listen()` method, I would guess that you get this error if you call `showAll()` *before* calling `listen()`.

A very simple field would be to assign `listWriters` to an empty list in its declaration, such that it can never be null:

```
private List<PrintWriter> listWriters = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();
```

Depending on the concurrency requirements of your application you may need to do something more elaborate, though the general principle is that you must initialise `listWriters` **before** you try to read from it.

Comment: Or `listen()` and `showAll()` are called on different objects.

Comment: @axtavt That's a good point and a potential cause of a bug (though just a refinement, since the problem is still that `listen()` hasn't been called *on the showAll object*).

Comment: That got rid of the NullPointerException, thanks for that, but now I still can't manage to get the messages to send, even though there are no errors. Any ideas why?

Comment: @BlH It depends, what was your fix - initialising the variable in the declaration?  If so, this just means it will be empty instead of null when `showAll` is called.  The root problem is that `listen()` wasn't called beforehand, so no PrintWriters were added to the list.  If you haven't fixed *this*, then you're still going to have no writers to print the `msg` to.

Answer (score 0):

You must be calling `showAll` method before `listen` method.
Your `ListWriters` is not getting initialized inside your `listen` method before your `showAll` method.

Answer (score 0):

That may be because, you have initialized your `listWriters` inside `listen()` method.

So, if your `showAll()` method gets called before `listen()` method, it will get a `null` value for your `listWriters` (Assuming that you have declared `listWriters` as instance variable, and have not initialized there itself).

You can try `initializing` it at the place you declared it.

```
private List<PrintWriter> listWriters = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();
```